# Why is indexing used in in the ICollection<T> Interface implementation example in Microsoft's documentation, if you cannot use it?

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerator, icollection

I'm trying to understand how to implement generic collections and the IEnumerator interface; I'm using the [Documentation provided to do so](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1?view=net-5.0#code-try-1).

In the given example the enumerator's method MoveNext() is implemented as follows:

```
public bool MoveNext()
{
    //Avoids going beyond the end of the collection.
    if (++curIndex >= _collection.Count)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        // Set current box to next item in collection.
        curBox = _collection[curIndex];
    }
    return true;
}
```

`curIndex` is used to as index for `BoxCollection`, which implements `ICollection`. If I try to do the same I get "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection...".

Is the documentation wrong, or is it me not doing something correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BoxCollection` itself implements the indexer:

```
public Box this[int index]
{
    get { return (Box)innerCol[index]; }
    set { innerCol[index] = value; }
}
```

(line 129-133 of the sample you linked to)

You're right that you can't use the indexer on a class that implements `ICollection<T>` - unless that class also implements an indexer.

Answer (score 1):

In the sample code in the documentation `_collection` is a BoxCollection, which is an ICollection also, but in that manifestation it’s typed as a BoxCollection and can therefore have indexing applied because BoxCollection implements a `this[int]` indexer property

Had the sample code declared `_collection` as some `ICollection<T>`, their code would get the same error yours does; in other words the indexability comes from their variable being an indexable type, which is unrelated to it also implementing ICollection (ICollection does not mandate provision of an indexer)